# WMIC Uninstall Roblox

Tags: batch-file, windows-10, uninstallation, roblox, wmic

I want to uninstall Rollox in cmd, Code:

```
@echo off
wmic product where "description='???' " uninstall
del /f %LocalAppdata%\Roblox
del /f %Temp%\Roblox
```

Do I use "Roblox" or "Roblox Player for XXX" for description?

Comment: It is recommended that you do not use Win32_Product *(`Product` is an alias for that in `WMIC`)*. When it enumerates all of the 'products', it performs a status check, and can repair/modify things. You should also be aware that Win32_Product, only enumerates those products which were installed using Microsoft Installer. Also, to specifically answer your question, you'd use the `Like` operator and `Call Uninstall`, e.g. `WMIC Product Where "Name Like 'Roblox%%'" Call Uninstall`

Answer (score 1):

I found another method:

```
RobloxPlayerLauncher.exe -uninstall
```

Answer (score 0):

Batch

```
@echo off

del C:\Users\ur name\AppData\Local\Roblox
```

PYTHON

```
import os

name = os.getlogin()

os.system(f'del C:/Users/{name}/AppData/Local/Roblox
```

Comment: No, it will still be in control panel.(Can't remove)